# NASM Notify-send?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, nasm

is there a way to display a message like the notify-send command in the linux terminal, coded in NASM?

I am using this command in Ubuntu:

```
notify-send "Test"
```

Would it be possible to display a similar thing using NASM?

Answer (score 0):

You want to send text to the desktop and display in the popup?  Well, I knew nothing about the `notify-send` thingy so I did a search and found that you could write something using the notify libs.  All in all, it took me 10 minutes to read some docs, and sample code and write this...

```
bits 64 
extern notify_init, notify_notification_new, notify_notification_show, notify_uninit

extern exit

section .data
name            db  "Sample Notification", 0
title           db  "Just a test", 0

global main
section .text
main:
    mov     rdi, name
    call    notify_init 

    mov     rdx, 0
    mov     rsi, title
    mov     rdi, name
    call    notify_notification_new

    mov     rsi, 0
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    notify_notification_show

    call    notify_uninit

    call    exit
```

makefile:

```
APP = notify
$(APP): $(APP).o
    gcc -o $(APP) $(APP).o -lnotify

$(APP).o: $(APP).asm
    nasm -f elf64 $(APP).asm
```

You will need to install `libnotify-dev` either with `apt-get` or your package manager

It should be similar for 32 bit systems.

[Gnome Notify Docs](https://developer-next.gnome.org/libnotify/0.7/NotifyNotification.html)

Comment: Strange, I couldn't find ANYTHING on the web, I only found my own question on stackoverflow.. However, thanks, I will take a look! Also, since I'm pretty new to linux, would the notify also show on systems which don't have libnotify-dev installed, after I compiled it?

Comment: Nice example.  Didn't know that it could be done.  Just a minor issue I've encountered.  The program isn't compileable anymore without -fPIE and even than I couldn't compile it.
A solution for this is (with the original code slightly modified:
replace main with _start and makefile:
    BIN=notify
NASM=/usr/bin/nasm
NASMOPTS=-felf64 -Fdwarf
LDOPS=-melf_x86_64 -g --dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
LIBS=-lc -lnotify

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(BIN)

clean:
 rm -rf $(BIN)

%: %.asm
 $(NASM) $(NASMOPTS) -o $@.o $<
 $(LD) $(LDOPS) -o $@ $@.o $(LIBS)
 rm -f $@.o

Answer (score 0):

Nice example.  Didn't know that it could be done.  Just a minor issue I've encountered.  I can't compile it without -fPIE and even with the use of it I couldn't compile it neither (perhaps C specialists cn help me out).

A solution for this is (with the original code slightly modified:
replave global main with global _start and
the label main: with _start:
then use next makefile:

```
BIN=notify
NASM=/usr/bin/nasm
NASMOPTS=-felf64 -Fdwarf
LDOPS=-melf_x86_64 -g --dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
LIBS=-lc -lnotify

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(BIN)

clean:
rm -rf $(BIN)

%: %.asm
    $(NASM) $(NASMOPTS) -o $@.o $<
    $(LD) $(LDOPS) -o $@ $@.o $(LIBS)
    rm -f $@.o
```